# How to call firebase gen2 callable function from unity?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm implementing a server in Unity as a Firebase callable function.

I recently heard that gen2 was released and tried to change it.
But I couldn't call it in Unity.
The reason seems to be that gen2 doesn't have allUsers permission.

how can i call it?

P.s. Is it correct that the reason gen1's callable function has allUsers permission is to access other functions of Firebase?
Am I understanding correctly?